# AmStockChart period selection changes to YTD (AmCharts)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using AmStockChart. The requirement here was to update the chart data on period selection. This works fine as we receive a period selection event and when this event occurs we update the chart with latest data. The period selector I have configured is 1M, 3M, 6M, 1Y, YTD and 3Y. The data I have is of 8 months.

The problem I am facing is when I change the period selector to 1Y, after updating the data it falls back to YTD i.e. it selects YTD again. However this is not happening when I select 1M, 3M and 6M, in these cases the selection does not changes to YTD.

Is it happening because I have only 8 months data and when I select 1Y, since there is only 8 months data it selects YTD? Is it the desired behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't replicate that. Would you be able create a https://codepen.io/ replicating the issue?

Comment: @Darlesson.. Thanks for responding. Did you call validateData() method after updating the chart data?